# Lambda function in tensorflow to do some changes to the data inside the model

Tags: tensorflow, lambda, deep-learning, model, custom-function

My goal is changing the data inside the model using lambda function

the code fails at the last part in model.predict
can someone help me fix this or give me a similar one if you have?

```
import glob
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from os.path import basename, join
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras import layers
from sklearn.metrics import auc, average_precision_score
import numpy as np
import base64
import cv2

#this is the function that i want to call inside the model 
#it take th data which in an image encoded base64 and it decode it back into a numpy array
 
def base64_decoder(inputs):

  binary_data = base64.b64decode(inputs)
  img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(binary_data, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

  return img



#this is the model i'm using to test

model_handle="https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/efficientnet_v2_imagenet1k_s/feature_vector/2"
INPUT_SIZE=(331, 331,3)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(base64_decoder),
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=INPUT_SIZE),
    hub.KerasLayer(model_handle, trainable=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(), metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC(curve='PR')])


# now i will test the model
im = np.random.rand(331,331,3)
img = np.expand_dims(im, axis=0)
#encode the random image
_, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', im)
jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode(buffer)
value=jpg_as_text.decode('utf-8')
#predict
print(model.predict(value))
```

also i may change the lambda function to a full custom function, what do you think?

Comment: Are you trying to inject image-reader inside your model? If so, not that, it will fallback to CPU. Apart from that, have you tried to create a custom layer (instead of lambda expression)?

Comment: yes its kind of image reader. I want to feed the model a string (image that is coded in base64) and inside the model the decoding will happen then the model will continue as if its a normal image. -- can you explain more your point?-- and i haven't tryed a custom function yet, i want to try this lambda function since its way simpler.